# How to load json response which contain string values only to a combo box already created

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a String array containing some names. I return it as a `Json` response and now I need to load those names in to a combo box in my `html` page. Combo box have been already created ans say its id is names. This is the function I wrote.

```
function loadSiteOfficers(ele){

    var selected = ele.value;
    if(selected == "Site Officer"){

        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/TFProject/load_officers.htm",

            success : function(response) {

                if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
                    alert(response.result);
                    // load response results to the combo box
                } else {
                    ////// some code here 
                }
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

`alert(response.result)` gives me names separated by commas. They are retrieved from the database.
I am bit confused here and need to know how to load the data. I will be grateful if you can help me
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this...

```
$.each(response.result, function(key, value) {
    $('#names').append($('<option></option>').val(key).html(value));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! you are my hero. But one thing to know other than the question. Why people keep voting down my question, If you were able to understand what the question is, why other people vote down the question? :(

Comment: Yes I see more and more people voting questions and answers down that are completely normal... I don't know why.